# Find the value of integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Let $f: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$f(x)=\int_{1/x}^x e^{t+1/t} \frac{dt}{t}$$ then $$\int_{-1}^1 f(2^x)dx$$ is
>
> (a) 1
>
> (b) 2

I tried to solve this problem by differentiated but I didn't proceed so please help how shall I think about this help
Thanks .

Comment: Show your solution

Comment: Okk I will edit my question then pls help me how I shall I proceed..

Comment: Did I reproduce your problem correctly in my edit?

Answer (score 3):

In general, we have $$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \mathrm{d}x$$.

Therefore,  in this case, we should have:
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(2^x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^1 f(2^{-x}) \mathrm{d}x$$

Hence,

$$\int_{-1}^1 f(2^x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 f(2^x) + f(2^{-x}) \mathrm{d}x $$

But clearly,

\begin{align*} 
f(2^x) + f(2^{-x}) &= \int_{2^{-x}}^{2^x} e^{t+\frac{1}{t}}\frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d}t + \int_{2^{x}}^{2^{-x}} e^{t+\frac{1}{t}}\frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{2^{-x}}^{2^x} e^{t+\frac{1}{t}}\frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d}t - \int_{2^{-x}}^{2^{x}} e^{t+\frac{1}{t}}\frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d}t \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Therefore,
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(2^x) \mathrm{d}x = 0$$

Comment: Pleasure was all mine!